# Aggregated Regressors and standard errors

Tags: regression, clustering, standard-error, linear, heteroscedasticity

Suppose we have some aggregated regressors and some that vary across all individuals. E.g. individual data on workers and aggregated data on the level of the US-states. We could either account for cluster-robust standard errors or aggregate the individual data on the same level and run the regression on the collapsed data (thereby losing within-cluster variance). But if we want to do the second approach and aggregate all data and then run the regression, are the default standard errors legit? Should I still care about cluster-robust standard errors and what about heteroscedasticity?

Comment: Can you give some more details? If you have a lot of data from many US states, maybe look into multilevel (mixed) models?